# Manually creating persistent volume on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-ebs

When I create PersistentVolumeClaim, it will dynamically create EBS volume with PersistentVolume on EKS.

I'm trying to create new PersistentVolume manually and bind it to new PersistentValumeClaim, but once I create it, it does not create EBS volume.

Where is PersistentVolume created?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv1
  labels:
    type: storage1
    app: rabbitmq1   
spec:
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: pvc1
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: "/etc/rabbitmq"
  storageClassName: gp2
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    type: storage1
    app: rabbitmq1
  name: pvc1
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: What is the output of `kubectl get storageclasses` ? Is `gp2` storage class marked as the default one ?

Answer (score 0):

You created a host path volume, that is from your spec:

```
  hostPath:
    path: "/etc/rabbitmq"
```

Just remove that path and K8s will create a new PV in with a EBS backend.

Comment: I got `The PersistentVolume "pv1" is invalid: spec: Required value: must specify a volume type`

Comment: So to answer the original question, my spec actually mounted local folder on Node?

Comment: Right, you mounted a local folder from a node. What about a error - you should specify a volume type, check [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes). But I highly recommend you to create just a PVC and it will creates a PV for you automatically. Of course, if you don't what to bind some pre-created EBS volume to your PV, but I don't see it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create new PersistentVolume manually and bind it to new
>   PersistentValumeClaim, but once I create it, it does not create EBS
>   volume.

As far as I understand you, you want to provision your storage manually, so you cannot expect that at the same time EBS volume, which is specific AWS storage type, will be created.

Look, what you defined in your yaml manifests is manual provisioning using your node local storage and has nothing to do with EBS. It seems to me that you confuse two concepts: manual and dynamic storage provisioning. Let's clarify it a bit. You could actually choose two different paths and decide to use either manual provisioning or dynamic one but not both of them at the same time.

1. as @Anton Kostenko suggested in his answer you may give up on using your local node storage, delete the mentioned fragment from your manifest and let **Kubernetes** and **AWS** with its **EBS** do it for you **dynamically**. You will need only to define `PersistentVolumeClaim`, choosing the proper `storageClassName` and `PV` will be provisioned automatically.
2. you may follow your original idea of creating `PersistentVolume` **manually** using `hostPath`. In this case you need to set `storageClassName` to `manual` in both `PersistentVolume` (which in this case is manually defined by you unlike in the 1st case) and `PersistentVolumeClaim` as in [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) example from official Kubernetes documentation. I've just checked it and it works perfectly. It's important to use same storage class so both `PV` and `PVC` can be bound together.

If you decide to choose the second path, your particular yaml manifests will look like that:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv1
  labels:
    type: storage1
    app: rabbitmq1   
spec:
  claimRef:
    namespace: default
    name: pvc1
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: "/etc/rabbitmq"
  storageClassName: manual
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    type: storage1
    app: rabbitmq1
  name: pvc1
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Once you put it let's say in a file `storage.yaml` simply issue the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f storage.yaml
```

And in a while both your `pv` and `pvc` will be created and you should see their status as `Bound`:

```
$ kubectl get pv
NAME             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pv1              1Gi        RWX            Retain           Bound    default/pvc1            manual                  33s


$ kubectl get pvc
NAME            STATUS   VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc1            Bound    pv1              1Gi        RWX            manual         38s
```